# sql server parse text to float then perform calculation and display with other fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have tried several different ways to search for a solution and have not found what I am looking for.

I need to parse an nvarchar(max) field that has 141 numbers separated by commas.  That much I have figured out.

```
SET @vData = (SELECT events FROM dbo.eventsTable WHERE eventID = input parameter);
SET @vData - LTRIM(RTRIM(@vData)) + ',';
SET @vpos = CHARINDEX(',', @vData, 1)  -- Obtain the starting position of the comma in the string

IF REPLACE(@vData, ',', '') <> ''
BEGIN
    WHILE @vpos > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @vInt = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@vData, @vpos -1)));
        SET @vDataNum = CAST(@vInt AS FLOAT);
        IF @vInt <> ''
             BEGIN
                SET @multiplier = (SELECT multiplier FROM dbo.multiplierTable mt WHERE mt.eventID = input parameter);
                SET @vCalcDataNum = @vDataNum * @vmultiplier;
        SET @vData = RIGHT(@vData, LEN(@vData) - @vpos);
        SET @vpos = CHARINDEX(',', @vData, 1);
    END;
END;
```

Where it starts to become a problem is that I need to pull several other fields from other tables all related to the input parameter and then display those fields along with the parsed numbers.  I also have to perform a calculation on those numbers which is why they need to be changed from nvarchar to float.

I am beginning to think I am going to have to write all of this out to a table in order to get that to work.  I really don't want to have to create a table with over 160 columns.

I have millions of records that need to be processed.

Any help is appreciated.

Additional information:

Basic Query

```
SELECT t1.field1, t1.field2, t2.field3, t3.field4, t5.field5, t7.field6, t9.field7
FROM dbo.table1 t1
INNER JOIN dbo.table2 t2 ON t2.table1ID = t1.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.table3 t2 ON t3.table2ID = t2.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.table4 t2 ON t4.table3ID = t3.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.table5 t2 ON t5.table4ID = t4.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.table6 t2 ON t6.table5ID = t5.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.table7 t2 ON t7.table6ID = t6.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.table8 t2 ON t8.table7ID = t7.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.table9 t2 ON t9.table8ID = t8.ID
WHERE t3.eventID = input parameter
AND t9.data4 > 0
AND t9.data5 > 1
```

t9.field7 is a varchar(max) and the data looks like 0,0,0,0,5,0,8,2,0,0,3,2,4,0,4....   There are 141 numbers in this field that need to be parsed and then have a calculation run on them.

The customer wants the output to look like:

Column Headings.....

t1.field1 | t1.field2 | t2.field3 | t3.field4 | t5.field5 | t7.field6 | cpv1 | cpv2 | cpv3 | ... | cpv141

t1.field1 | t1.field2 | t2.field3 | t3.field4 | t5.field5 | t7.field6 | cpv1 | cpv2 | cpv3 | ... | cpv141

etc.

cpv = the parsed value after the calculation has been performed

I added the calculation part to the loop above which is what I was working on originally.  It works and produces the correct numbers but not in the format requested.

Comment: You need to start with a string splitter that doesn't use loops. Pick any of these. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings After that your question becomes extremely fuzzy. See if you just having a decent splitter will get you going. If not, come back and provide a lot more details and we can help.

Comment: @SeanLange - Thank you.  The link is helpful and I am still working to see if any of the options will produce the results we are looking for.  I have added more information.  Let me know if this does not clarify things.   I was trying not to write a novel.  :)

Comment: Once you split that awful column you will probably need to do a pivot or crosstab to spit it back out into columns. Any chance you have the ability to fix that column? Storing data delimited like that is a nightmare. But sometimes it can't be changed either.